# Generating Pulse Amplitude Modulation using sine wave and PWM signal using python

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, pwm

I am using the below codes so as to generate a Pulse Amplitude
  Modulation signal by using the Boolean operation between sine wave and 
  Pulse Width Modulation(PWM) signal.I am using the vectorisation method 
  so as to get zero values where the PWM signal is low(zero or false) and
  sine wave where the PWM values as high (True or one). Please refer the 
  below screen shot for the required output.In addition to this how do 
  you automate the PAM wave generation as I am facing problem with 
  spacing of x values?

```
        import numpy as np
        import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
        from pylab import *

        percent=50.0
        TimePeriod=10.0 #Frozen Value Do not change
        Cycles=10 #Frozen Value Do not change
        dt=0.01 #Frozen Value Do not change

        t=np.arange(0,Cycles*TimePeriod,dt); 
        pwm= t%TimePeriod<TimePeriod*percent/100

        x=np.linspace(-10,10,10000) #Frozen Value Do not change
        y=(np.sin(x))

        y[(pwm =='False')] = 0      #Vectorisation for zero values
        y[(pwm =='True')] = (y-pwm) # #Vectorisation for sine wave
        plt.plot(t,y)

        plt.ylim([-3,3])
        plt.grid()
        plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When removing the line `y[(pwm =='True')] = (y-pwm)` (which I don't understand) and not comparing to strings, you would get the following, which looks pretty much like the desired plot.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

percent=40.0
TimePeriod=10.0
Cycles=30
dt=0.01

t=np.arange(0,Cycles*TimePeriod,dt); 
pwm= (t%TimePeriod) < (TimePeriod*percent/100)

x=np.linspace(-10,10,len(pwm))
y=(np.sin(x))

y[pwm == 0] = 0

plt.plot(t,y)

plt.ylim([-3,3])
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: importance of being earnest: Great answer,1+ vote for that.